# How do I replace multiple blank spaces occuring in a text file with a single space in python

Tags: python, replace, file-handling

```py
with open("test.234.txt", 'r') as f:
    a=f.read()

with open("test234(double space replaced by singleones)" ,"w+") as f:
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if( a[i]+a[i+1] == "  "):
            a[i].replace(a[i],"")
            a[i+1].replace(a[i+1]," ")
            f.write(a[i]+a[i+1])

        else:
            f.write(a[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split string by default splits string at spaces and ignores multiple consecutive spaces:

```
with open("test.234.txt", 'r') as f:
    a=f.read()

with open("test234(double space replaced by singleones)" ,"w+") as f:
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        f.write(' '.join(a[i].split()))
```

Comment: This will ignore the new line character in string. If we use readlines() and then iterate it, the new lines are not deleted.
My final code:

with open("test.234.txt", 'r') as f:
    a=f.readlines()
    
with open("test234(double space replaced by singleones)" ,"w+") as f:
    #print(c)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c=a[i].split()
        f.write(" ".join(c))     
        f.write("\n")

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

with open("test.234.txt", 'r') as f:
    with open("test234(double space replaced by singleones)" ,"w+") as out_f: 
       a = f.read()
       a = re.sub('\s+', ' ', a))
       out_f.write(a
```

Answer (score 0):

This will open up text.txt and replace all double spaces with a single space. You will still need to write `b` to your text file. You don't need to do it line by line

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()

b = a.replace("  ", " ")
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("test.234.txt", "r") as f:
    a=f.readlines()
    
with open("test234(double space replaced by singleones)" ,"w+") as f:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        f.write(" ".join(a[i].split()))     
        f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

I started with perl and switched to python so i always replace on each line of the file

```
import re
fout = open("test234(double space replaced by singleones)" ,"w+")
with open("test.234.txt", 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(re.sub('\s+',' ',line))
```